# How to access ajax timer control in my master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, .net-4.0

using VS 2010, C#, asp.net

I have timer control in my master page and I want to access it from my master page .cs file

But it didn't work, even when I used this code

```
((System.Web.UI.Timer)this.FindControl("Timer1")).Enable = false;
```

it look like VS don't know what is tiemr control ?!!!

please advice,

my first try was just,
Timer1.Enable=false;

and it didn't work and got this in when I run the web

"Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Enable' and no extension method 'Enable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

here is my asp.net code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Ads_master.master.cs" Inherits="Ads_master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Every200</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 22%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 263px;
        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 49px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>

            <div class="title">
                <h1 style="font-family: Tahoma">
                    EVERY200.com
                </h1>
               <p style="color: #FFFF66; font-weight: 700; font-family: Tahoma;">   &#160;&#160;   &#160;&#160;  stop hunt cents, start hunt dollars</p>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table class="style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style2">
                                &nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_counter" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                                    Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_message" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                                    Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="AdsCaptchaHolder" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style3" style="text-align: left">
                                &nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="style3" style="text-align: left">
                                &nbsp;
                                <asp:Button ID="Button_verify" runat="server" BackColor="#0033CC" 
                                    BorderStyle="Solid" Height="100%" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Verify" 
                                    Visible="False" Width="100%" />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="style3" style="text-align: left">
                                &nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                                    ImageUrl="http://images.neobux.com/imagens/banner5.gif" 
                                    PostBackUrl="http://www.neobux.com/?r=amrosama77" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
           <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" align="left">



        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can the problem be that my class code inherits from " System.Web.UI.MasterPage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added timer control in Master Page file, you can access timer control directly in Masterpage code behind file.

Please refer below code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1">
    </asp:Timer>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Code behind file :(.cs file)

```
Timer1.Enabled = false;
```

Please check if you have added the ScriptManager code.

Hi,

Please try this code and check.

((Timer)this.FindControl("timer1")).Enabled = false;

Comment: this was my first try, and VS said 'Timer1' does not exists in the current context, and yes I added the ScriptManager

Comment: Timer does not contain "Enable" property. Instead it contains "Enabled". Please try with Enabled property

Comment: it's not about enable or enabled, when I write Timer1.Enabled=false; the Timer1 marked as not defined

Comment: Please try this code, ((Timer)this.FindControl("timer1")).Enabled = false;

Answer (score 1):

try this,

`Timer tm = Master.FindControl("Timer1") as Timer;`
`tm.Enabled = false;`